# EF 'Cannot insert duplicate key in object' when updating an existing object in a repository

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I fairly inexperienced with EF, and I have been struggling with what I am sure is a rather trivial issue, for quite a while.
I have two tables, SpecialCondition and SpecialConditionDepartment. A special condition can apply to several departments, so in the SpecialConditionDepartment table I store the conditionID and the deparmentID. If a condition applies to two departments, there will be two rows in the SpecialConditionDepartment table, with the same conditionID.

```
public class SpecialCondition
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SpecialConditionDepartment> Departments { get; set; }
}

 public class SpecialConditionDepartment
{
    private SpecialConditionDepartment()
    {
    }

    public SpecialConditionDepartment(int conditionID, int departmentID)
    {
        ConditionID = conditionID;
        DepartmentID = departmentID;
    }

    public int ConditionID { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
}


 var specialCondition =modelBuilder.Entity<SpecialCondition>().ToTable("SpecialCondition");
        specialCondition.HasMany(o => o.Departments)
            .WithOptional()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ConditionID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<SpecialConditionDepartment>().ToTable("SpecialConditionDepartment")
            .HasKey(c => new { c.ConditionID, c.DepartmentID });
```

And finally the update method, which is inside a web service, is fairly simple. I grab the object from the DB, update name and Departments list and then update using the generic repository Update():

```
 public SpecialConditionDto UpdateCondition(SpecialConditionDto dto)
 {
        SpecialCondition specialcondition = specialConditionRepository.GetById(dto.ID);

        specialcondition.Name = dto.Name;
        specialcondition.Departments =
            mapper.Map<ICollection<SpecialConditionDepartmentDto>, ICollection<SpecialConditionDepartment>>(
                dto.Departments);
         specialConditionRepository.Update(specialcondition);
         unitOfWork.Commit();
         return specialcondition.Map<SpecialConditionDto>();
}
```

The SpecialConditionRepository inherits from the RepositoryBase, which in turn inherits from IRepository

```
public class SpecialConditionRepository : RepositoryBase<SpecialCondition>, ISpecialConditionRepository
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
```

And the repository base, where all the generic Add, GetById, Update and so on are defined

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
  protected IDbSet<T> Set
  {
    get { return Context.Set<T>(); }
  }

  protected RepositoryBase()
  {
    DatabaseFactory = new DatabaseFactory();
  }
  private EFContext _context;
  public EFContext Context
  {
    get { return _context ?? (Context = DatabaseFactory.Create()); }
    set { _context = value; }
  }
}
```

In the context is where the models and IDBSets are defined

```
public IDbSet<SpecialCondition> SpecialConditions { get; set; }
public IDbSet<SpecialConditionDepartment> SpecialConditionDepartments { get; set; }
```

The same code works for creating a special condition. When trying to update however, it does not understand that I want it to update the departments as well, and it tries to add new rows to the SpecialConditionDepartment table, which ends up crashing my code.

What I am missing?

Comment: You are missing the section of what 'GetById' is returning.  My guess off the top of my head is that your 'DepartmentId' is not getting populated.  This sets off an insert routine.  That conflicts with a unique constraint that already exists.  I would just set a breakpoint and observe that the object 'specialcondition' has the proper properties.

Comment: Edited for clarity. I grab the object from the db and then update the name and Departments list. The values on the department list (ConditionID and DepartmentID) are valid. The problem is that when I update a condition with ID 13 that applies to department 6 it tries to add the row ConditionID=13 DepartmentID 6 to the SpecialConditionDepartment table, it does not understand that that row already existed from before

Comment: Okay I was off with the key I was stating anyways as I was looking at your lower table object.  Is the code you are displaying directly from your repo class?  Because what is the 'specialConditionRepository' object?  Generally with EF you do a 'context' like (var context = new MyEFContext()) and then do work in that.  You are mixing an update and a commit to be two different objects.  But you are saying it works for an insert so I am curious as it may be that that is not getting commited yet appears with the first insert and then blows up on the second.

Comment: I added some more stuff, but I reckon this is likely getting too confusing. I should have said this is a tiny bit of a huge project which was set up several years ago and none of the original devs are still around, which does not help. The context is where we define all the IDBsets and models, and the repo is where the db stuff happens. The code actually crashes in the commit, which is when stuff is actually written to the db, not in the repo.Update

Comment: Right but the problem could be erring in the context but the method is the repo is causing the problem.  This part: 'specialConditionRepository.Update(specialcondition);unitOfWork.Commit();' is strange in that most EF code does work on a context and adds to that off of an IDBSet and then updates.  I will give a more thorough example in a few minutes with some test code that shows the EF layer and made up repo layer too.

Comment: It really depends on how exactly the `specialConditionRepository` `GetById` and `Update` methods are implemented (unfortunately not shown here).

Answer (score 0):

Okay to start off I think we should keep this simple and just define two tables in a database:

```
tdCountry has a CountryId(int, PrimaryKey), CountryName(varchar(128))
tePerson has a PersonId(int), FirstName(varchar(128), LastName(varchar(128)), CountryId(int, ForeignKey to tdCountry(CountryId))
```

I define these relationships in EF like so.  I call my EF container name 'TesterEntities' for reference.(shown later)

```
public partial class tdCountry
{
    public tdCountry()
    {
        this.tePerson = new HashSet<tePerson>();
    }

    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<tePerson> tePerson { get; set; }
}

public partial class tePerson
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CountryId { get; set; }

    public virtual tdCountry tdCountry { get; set; }
}
```

Now what you are doing is appearing to change many items at once from a single item.  I am not familiar with your repo but it appears to be whatever it is, is overkill and may be causing more problems than solutions.  Typically if I have a one to many relationship where one country can have many people.  I may want to update by performing an insert and then saying: "Hey update all or a portion to this now location."  I can do that with only a few lines of code in EF inside a context.  Like so:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  //This could be an add in a repo
  using (var context = new TesterEntities())
  {
    context.tdCountry.Add(new tdCountry { CountryName = "Canada" });
    context.SaveChanges();
  }

  //This could be an update in a repo
  using (var context = new TesterEntities())
  {
    var getNewCountry = context.tdCountry.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CountryName == "Canada");
    var people = context.tePerson.ToList();
    getNewCountry.tePerson = people;
    context.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

I am not certain but I know typically I usually walk on the line of a unit of work being wrapped in a context and then have that context exposed. This is done with a using statement and then disposing of it.  I also do my work and then generally reference the context's 'SaveChanges()' and avoid too much wrapping in a repo of renaming things.  I have worked at places where they rename things over and over that EF is doing and IMHO it adds complexity where none is needed.  The second method is really doing what you need.  Essentially I am getting the object I just created prior.  I then get a listing of the objects I need to update.  I then take the object in reference in memory related in this context and just assign it's property to what I want.  I then tell the context to SaveChanges() again and it understands how to run the updates.

If you are having problems it could be that you have references trying to update too many things instead of not enough and your objects are in seperate states.  You also could have issues if your relationships are not done correctly.  Typically if you are doing the typical display where you have an '*.edmx' file you can observe the relationships.

I would try to just get away from that repo until you can verify working code in a console app or smaller function.  Sometimes it helps to take a step back and refactor from scratch instead of working with many pieces you may or may not understand of why they were done a certain way.

Comment: thanks a lot for the advice. I will give this approach a try and see if I can get it to work!